# Handling version of module dependencies for multi-module

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a multi-module project with modules A and B, where A depends on B. I want to use a common version number for both modules in each build.

When I declare the dependency B in the pom of A, how do I specify the version number? Do I use a property declared in the parent pom?

First of all, I would like to avoid a duplicate handling of the version number. Secondly, I would like the project to work with Maven release plugin, so the dependency should automatically changed from SNAPSHOT to release when both modules are released.

Comment: Are both `A` and `B` modules of a common parent `pom` project? If so, then you can specify the version of `B` as `${project.version}` (maven built-in property) in `A/pom.xml`, assuming that both projects use the parent's version (not redeclaring the artifact version)

Comment: Thank you. Does this also work with Maven-release-plugin?

Comment: Yes, the release plugin is aware of it and, in my experience, does in fact update modules correctly.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Thank you again. You answered my question entirely.

Comment: First you can define a dependencyManagement in the root module for all modules and defining its version by using `${project.version]` or you use that simply in each module you have a inter module dependency which on the other hand makes it clear that you are making a inter module dependency and the release plugin works with that...